# Why does Android Studio insist that I make this void?

Tags: java, android-studio

I have a simple class here that consists of an array of words and what I was hoping to be the start of a method that grabs random words from that array. I do not understand Java as much, so I cannot understand why Android Studio wants me to return null on this.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class RandomSentence {
    public String[] mWords = {
        "string1", "string2", "string3", "string4"};

    public String getSentenceResult() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
            return this.mWords[new Random().nextInt(this.mWords.length)];
        }
    } // error appears here 
}
```

Comment: The ide doesn't realize that this code is always returning inside the loop, so because this method requires a String to be returned, it wants something, even a null to be returned.

Comment: Why do you have a for-loop inside getSentenceResult()? You return on the first iteration regardless.

Comment: Because I'm trying to figure out how to make it grab multiple words.

Comment: Then you will need to build a new string and not return inside the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have a return operator after the for loop, thus it's erroring out

```
import java.util.Random;

public class RandomSentence {
    public String[] mWords = {
        "string1", "string2", "string3", "string4"};

    public String getSentenceResult() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
            return this.mWords[new Random().nextInt(this.mWords.length)];
        }
        return "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not just Android studio, it is basic java principle. You need to declare the datatype relative to your return type locally then assigned the variable to your looped results. Now you can return your local variable below your method.

```
import java.util.Random;

    public class RandomSentence {
        public String[] mWords = {
            "string1", "string2", "string3", "string4"};
    
        public String getSentenceResult() {
            String result = ""; // declare locally
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
//assign to you return type
                 result= this.mWords[new Random().nextInt(this.mWords.length)];
            }
//return
            return result;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you 2 logic to achieve what you wanted,

```
public String getSentenceResult() {
    return this.mWords[new Random().nextInt(this.mWords.length)];
}
```

or

```
public String getSentenceResult(String[] words) {
    return words[new Random().nextInt(words.length)];
 }
```